Changing the placeholder color
I have this code and I want to change the color of the placeholder to white, the text is "E-mail" and it always turns to a light gray.
`<div class="col-md-12 newsletter-box">
                            <p><b><u style="color: #302e2f; text-decoration-thickness: 2px; text-   decoration-color: #c5d754; text-underline-offset: 30%">Receba ofertas e novidades:</u></b></p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input style="background-color: #302e2f; color: #ffffff" class="form-control flexy-newsletter-email" name="newsletter[email]" placeholder="E-mail">
                                    <b><button type="submit" style="background-color: #302e2f; color: #c5d754; border-color: #302e2f" class="flexy-newsletter-sigin btn-blue" title="Assinar">>></button></b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`

I tried to change the color doing the placeholder before but it didn't work.
